# SignalR: Can i send a message to the caller in a group?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

You can send a message to the caller if you don't use groups.
But I want to be able to send a message to a client when he joins the group.
Is this possible?

This is what I am using now:

**To caller if not using groups**

```
await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("update", "You have connected to the server.");
```

And this is what I found.

**From the working with groups page on the Microsoft website**


Send to **all** in group.

```
Clients.Group(groupName).addChatMessage(name, message);
```

All clients **except specified**.

```
Clients.Group(groupName, connectionId1, connectionId2).addChatMessage(name, message);
```

All clients **except caller**

```
Clients.OthersInGroup(groupName).addChatMessage(name, message);
```

Comment: What's the difference with sending to caller vs sending to caller in group? It's the caller in both cases?

Comment: From what i read on the Microsoft page is that you can only send to groups like i posted.

Comment: yes this is possible

Comment: How? Do I just use Clients.Caller.SendAsync? Or something else?

Comment: You need to add client in group by its ConnectionId and then its automatically assing to group thats he's added

Comment: For your knowledge, I added answer below view it and let know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add or remove your client to the group from your ChatHub like

```
public async Task JoinGroup(string name, string group)
{
    await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
}

public Task LeaveGroup(string name, string group)
{
    return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, group);
}
```

And in your `js` side you need to add the callback for above two methods,

```
$.connection.chatHub.server.joinGroup(connectionID, group);

$.connection.chatHub.server.leaveGroup(connectionID, group);
```